# Protractor ignores connection to DB via SSH

Tags: mysql, node.js, selenium, ssh, protractor

I have the next tricky task: I need to test a chat and then make a query to DB and check billing data.

We are using MySQL over SSH connection.
I found the next library to work with:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-ssh

I tried it and it works.
I run it with `node test.js`
But when I am trying to set it in my spec I see nothing in `console.log` and the spec always runs successfully even if I change SQL query to non-valid:

```
it('Log in with common form and filled params', function () {
    /*var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance();
    browser2.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
    browser2.get(browser.baseUrl);

    browser.pause();
    browser2.pause();*/


    mysqlssh.connect(
        {
            host: 'host',
            user: 'user',
            privateKey: fs.readFileSync('path to key')
        },
        {
            host: 'host',
            user: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
            database: 'db'
        }
    ).
        .then(client => {
            client.query('SELECT * FROM `agency`', function (err, results) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(results);
                mysqlssh.close()
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
});
```

I have no idea, how to change that. 
The only workaround is to create a test with Selenium driver and run it with Node, but it's an extra job.

Answer (score 0):

## you need to use done()

You need to do something with the `done` function. See the [jasmine documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.8/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support).

```
it('Log in with common form and filled params', (done) => {
    /*var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance();
    browser2.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
    browser2.get(browser.baseUrl);

    browser.pause();
    browser2.pause();*/


    mysqlssh.connect(
        {
            host: 'host',
            user: 'user',
            privateKey: fs.readFileSync('path to key')
        },
        {
            host: 'host',
            user: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
            database: 'db'
        }
    ).
        .then(client => {
            client.query('SELECT * FROM `agency`', function (err, results) {
                if (err) {
                  // if this is not caught, maybe use done.fail instead.
                  throw err; 
                }
                console.log(results);
                mysqlssh.close();
                done();
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            done.fail('some message');
        });
});
```

You need to provide a done or done.fail method in an async task for Jasmine to wait for this spec to be over before moving on to the next spec.

## debugging

Looking at the dependency for mysql-ssh, it uses a promise wrapper. https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Promise-Wrapper.md. However, after looking into the node-mysql2 repo, it is not clear whether these are asynchronous or synchronous.

Add extra logging:

```
mysqlssh.connect({ host: 'host', user: 'user', privateKey: fs.readFileSync('path to key')},
        { host: 'host', user: 'user', password: 'pass', database: 'db' }
    ).then(client => {
        console.log('connected');
        console.log(client);
        client.query('SELECT * FROM `agency`', (err, results, fields) => {
          // should try to catch errors, also should validate if
          // the query returns a promise or not
          // if query returns a promise, there should be a then to close and a catch for errors
          // should pick a reasonable place to add a done
          // and done.fail calls.

        });

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error caught');
        done.fail();
    });
```

Comment: done() is not necessary for protractor. However with done() nothing happens.

Comment: Actually in this case it is. The selenium webdriver promises are synced but selenium does not know about this promise because it was not part of the control flow.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, but now I have TypeError: client.query(...).then is not a function. Maybe I should add some package with require? Can you help me, please?

Comment: Alright my debugging is wrong, the query signature is string and callback function. I would check to see if the libraries to see if these are synchronous or asynchronous. I know about Protractor but I am not an expert at this (mysql-ssh) library.